# Statistical operations (mean) between raster with different extents

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm working with a satellite (SMAP) that has a temporal resolution of 3 days. So every day the sensor covers a portion of Brazil. I have the Geotiff files, but I need to calculate the mean values for the three images, but the mean will be calculated only for the pixels that overlap. In the end, I need a single image for the period of three days.

How can I do this?

In [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11uNOuQnrp2rL1_3pCIfQAz5xcjqzIi7E/view?usp=sharing) there is a file that contains the three images.

Here an example of one of these images:

[image: Image 1]

Comment: is there a specific nodata vlaue ?

Comment: Hi, @radouxju. All the values (black boundaries) outside are no data values. Default is -9999, but I converted these values as no data.

Answer (score 1):

you could use one of the raster calculator available in QGIS (QGIS raster calculator, gdal_calc, otbBandMath...), even if it could be long to write with more images. Don't work with the nodata values but directly with the original raster -9999 . The following syntax is for the "raster > raster calculator" and is based on the fact that boolean tests are translated into 0 (false) or 1 (true)

```
((im1@1>-9999)*im1@1 + (im2@1>-9999)*im2@1  + (im3@1>-9999)*im3@1 ) / ((im1@1>-9999)+ (im2@1>-9999)  + (im3@1>-9999) )
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents just about how to deal with different extents:

(Option 1) QGIS Align Rasters

- QGIS > Raster > Align Rasters
- Select one of your rasters as the reference
- All rasters, including reference raster, will be modified somewhat.
- You will likely lose one of row/column of the original set.

(Option 2) Reproject rasters

- QGIS > Raster > Projection > Warp
- It will change their CRS, and you will need to select appropriate CRS.
- All rasters will change but best option for your further analysis.

(Option 3) OTB (Orfeo Toolbox)

- OTB (or Monteverdi) > Superimpose
- It will align the data to fit with reference raster accurately. Reference raster stays unchanged.
- We do not have to change CRS.

I would recommend OTB, but it may depend on how you proceed with your further analysis.

Anyway, once your rasters are aligned, you can start calculation following the answer by [radouxju](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25070/radouxju).